# $\text{Calculate the value of} \ \left((1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...\frac{1}{10086})\times \left(10085!\right)+10081\right) \mod 10086$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

> $$\text{Calculate the value of} \ \left((1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...\frac{1}{10086})\times \left(10085!\right)+10081\right) \mod 10086$$

By emulating on the computer program, I found the answer is $10081$, which means that $(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...\frac{1}{10086})\times \left(10085!\right)$ is an integer divisible by $10086$.

But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: my guess for a start would be to rewrite the sum of fractions with each fraction having common denominator $10086!$,  this should get you each numerator is $\frac {10086!} n$,  try adding those up and see where that gest you?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what the heck is the point of putting in that $10081$ in the first place?

Comment: @fleablood Perhaps it serves as a hint, that the former operand is a multiple of $10086$. It can be any other integer in $[0, 10085]$, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

======== More accurate answer=====

$10086$ is not prime nor $2$ times a prime and $10086 > 9$.  $10085!$ is the product of all naturals numbers less than $1085$ and that will include all the many non-trivial factors of $10086$.  $\frac {10085!}n; 1\le n \le 10086$ will be the product of all natural numbers less than $1085$ except $n$.  $n$ might be a factor of $10086$ but there will be plenty of other numbers that are factors of $10086$ that will be included so $\frac {10085}n$ will always be a multiple of $10086$ and $(1+\frac 12 + ..... + \frac 1{10086})10085! = \sum_{n=1}^{10086} \frac {10085!}n$ will be the sum of terms all divisible by $10086$ and thus divisible by $10086$.

LEMMA:  If $M$ is not prime nor $2$ times the power of a prime and greater than $9$and $n$ is a natural number less than or equal to $M$ then $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ is a multiple of $M$.

Pf:  As $M$ is not prime nor $2$ times the power of a prime, we can find factors $j,k$ so that $2 < j \le k < \frac M2$.  $j, 2j, k, 2k < M-1$. If $j\ne k$ these are at least $3$ distinct numbers.  If $j=k$ then $j=k > 3$ and $j, 2j=2k, 3k < M-1$.  This are $3$ distinct numbers.

If $n\le M$ then $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ will be the product of all natural numbers less than or equal to $M-!$ except $n$.  If $j, 2j, k, 2k$ are four distinct numbers then at least $3$ of these will be included in the product.  Thus a multiple of $j$ and a multiple of $k$ will be included in the product and $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ will be a multiple of $jk =M$.

If $j\ne k$ but $k = 2j$ then $j, 2j=k, 2k$ are only $3$ distinct numbers.  That's okay.  $j$ and $2j=k$ are each multiples of $j$ and $k, 2k$ are multiples of $k$ and so least two of these will be include in the product. This will include a multiple of $j$ and a second number that is a multple of $k$.  And thus $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ will be a multiple of $jk =M$.

And if $j=k$ then $j=k, 2j=2k, 3j=3k$ will be three distinct numbers of which two will be included in the product.  One number (both actually) will be a multiple of $j$ and the other a multiple of $k$ so $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ will be a multiple of $jk =M$.

The end.

This fails if $M =2p$ where $p$ is and odd prime as $\frac {(2p-1)!}p$ will have no component that is a multiple of $p$.

It fails for $M=4$ as we don't have enough multiples of $2$ to spare. We only have one. $\frac{3!}n$ is not divisible by $2^2$.

It fails for $n=9$ because we don't have enough multiples of $3$ to spare. We only have two, $3$ and $6$. $\frac{8!}{3}$ and $\frac {8!}{6}$ is not divisible by $3^2$.

But for all other cases... we are good.

========= Old answer ======

$10086$ is not prime. And it is not $2$ times a prime.  $\frac {10085!}n$ is going to be a product of all integers up to $10085$ except $n$ and as such it will be a product of all the factors of $10086$ and $\frac {10085!}n$ will be a multiple of $10086$.

Details $10086 = 2\times 3 \times 1681$.  $ \frac{10085!}n= \prod_{k\in \{1,2,3,....,1085\}\setminus\{n\}} k$

Now we can note that all the numbers from $1$ to $1085$ will contain more than $2$ even numbers so even if $n$ is even there will be other components of $ {10085!}= \prod_{k\in \{1,2,3,....,1085\}\setminus\{n\}} k$ that are even so $ \frac{10085!}n$ will always be divisible by $2$.

And all the numbers from $10085$ will contain more than $2$ numbers divisible by $3$ so even if $n$ is divisible by $3$ there will be other components that are also divisible by $3$ so $ \frac{10085!}n$ will always be divisible by $3$.

And there are $5$ numbers that are divisible by $1681$.  So even if $n$ is divisible by $1681$ there will be other components divisible by $1681$ and so $ \frac{10085!}n$ will always be divisible by $1681$ always.

So $\frac {10085!}n$ will always be divisible by $10086$.  And so $(1+\frac 12 + ....)\times 10085!$ will be divisible by $10086$.

This would be true of *all* numbers $M$ that are neither prime nor $2$ times a prime.  We will always have $M$ divides $\frac {(M-1)!}n$ for any  $n: 1\le n \le n-1$

....

If you need more convincing.

If $n\ne 2$ then $\frac {10085!}n = 1\cdot 2\cdot .....\cdot (n-1)\dot (n+1)......\cdot 1085$ and $\frac {10085!}n$ is divisible by $2$.

If $n = 2$ then $\frac {10085!}n = 1\cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdot ... 10085$ so $\frac {10085!}n$ is divisible by $2$.

If $n\ne 3$ then $\frac {10085!}n = 1\cdot... \cdot 3\cdot ....... \cdot 10085$ and is divisible by $3$.

If $n=3$ then $\frac {10085!}3 = 1\cdot 2\cdot 4 \cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot ..... \cdot 10085$ and is divisible by $3$.

If $n\ne 1681$ then $\frac {10085!}n = 1\cdot.... \cdot 1681 .... \cdot 10085$ and is divisible by $1681$.

And if $n = 1681$ (I think this is the leap that is hard to make) then $\frac {1085}{1681} = 1\cdot 2\cdot ..... \cdot 1680 \cdot 1682 .....   \cdot 3362 .... \cdot 10085$ and is divisible by $1681$ (because $3362 = 2\times 1681$)

Comment: Did you mean "x 10085! will be divisible *by* 10086"?

Comment: Argh.  Actually even if $M = 2p$ where $p$ is prime $p \ge 3$ this will be fine.  The only cases where this won't work are if $M$ is prime or $M =p^2$ were $p$ is a prime less than or equal to $3$.  I'll try to rewrite this up sometime today.

Comment: "Did you mean "x 10085! will be divisible by 10086"? "  Yes, didn't I say that?  What did I say?